# how to append directive restrict='A' to existing element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

There is a need to append custom directive wich is restricted to 'A' (attribute) to some of the instances of others directives (the second one, e.g.) *after* it was rendered using ng-repeat.

```
<some-directive ng-repeat="item in vm.items"></some-directive>
```

that 'A'-directive is derived from uib-popover, but I suppose solution for pure uib-popover will also work. Also, it would be great to safely remove than appended popovers later.

Any suggestions how to implement it?

Comment: What happens when you just do it: `<some-directive ng-repeat="item in vm.items" your-directive></some-directive>`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way::

Create custom directive with priority more than **ng-repeat priority**....

ng-repeat has **1000** priority.

```
angular.module('x').directive('customDir', function() {
    return {
        priority: 1001, // as ng-repeat has priority level 1000
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function () {
            return function () {...}
        }
    }
})
```

Uses::

```
<some-directive ng-repeat="item in vm.items" custom-dir ></some-directive>
```